# SpringMvc controller to returns JSON, displays error: HTTP status 406

Tags: json, spring, model-view-controller, controller

I am learning spring 4.2.4 by writing some webapp code.The idea is to return json file by controller.
 I have already posted my questions before couple of days ago and still no i could get the right suggestions for my case. I am trying all the suggestions given by stackoverfolow none of the suggestions could work for me. Here is my controller:
.....

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getmessages",method=RequestMethod.GET,    produces="application/json")
 @ResponseBody
 public Map<String,Object> getMessage(Principal prinicipal){

    List<Message>message=null;
    if(prinicipal==null){
        message=new ArrayList<Message>();

    }
    else{
        String username=prinicipal.getName();
        message=usersService.getMessage(username);
    }

    Map<String,Object> data= new HashMap<String,Object>();
    data.put("message", message);
    data.put("number", message.size());
    System.out.println("message has to be her\n"+message);
    System.out.println("Number  message has to be her is..."+message.size());
    return data;
}
```

the message content which is to be retrieved from mysql is propely displayed in console.
The problem is conversion to JSON and return the result. I have been trying by change the jackson 1.9.x  jar to jackson-fasterxml-2.x and it does not work. All other possible configuration of servlete also does not work for me.
When I add jackson-fasterxml-databind ....it displays file download dialogue box for filename"getmessages". to download and save...

I am very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved this problem as follow:
I changed my return type from MAP to String and I converted my MAP to String in side my CONTROLLER as:

1. Converting my Map to String:

   ```
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     String jsonFromMap = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
   ```
2. I have also changed my dependencies as:

   ```
      <dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.3</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.3</version>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.3</version>
   ```
3. Inside @RequestMapping change

   ```
       produces=application/json
   ```

   to

   ```
     produces=text/html
   ```

I think the problem is with browser unable to understand application/json and returning Map............
Any how I did what I want to do even-though I do not know how I did it!